# What are the benefits of having two models instead of one?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I've a Django model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

And a team model

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then, I would like to add a 'coach' property which is a one to one relationship to person. If I am not wrong, I have two ways of doing it.

The first approach would be adding the field to Team:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coach = models.OneToOneField(Person, related_name='master')
```

The second one would be creating a new model:

```
class TeamCoach(models.Model):
    team = models.OneToOneField(Team)
    coach = models.OneToOneField(Person)
```

Is this right ? is there a big difference for practical purposes ? which are the pro and cons of each approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will say *NEITHER*, as every **Person** has a **Team** and if every **Team** has a **Coach**, it's rather redundant circulation and somewhat unnecessary.

Better to add a field in **Person** called **type** directly is more clean and direct, something like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # use _ if you care about i18n
    TYPES = ('member', 'member',
             'coach', 'coach',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPES)
```

Although I would seriously consider refactoring **Person** to be more generic and get **Team** to have a **ManyToMany** to **Person**... in that case, you can re-use **Person** in other areas, like Cheerleaders.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # use _ if you care about i18n
    TYPES = ('member', 'member',
             'coach', 'coach',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPES)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='master')
```

Make your models more generic and DRY, they should be easily manageable and not tightly coupled to certain fields (unless absolutely necessary), then the models are more future proof and will not fall under migration nightmare that easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I like and I believe your approach is very elegant, however these models wouldn't assure there's just one coach per team, right ?, i don't believe it's a big deal but just checking if i get it right.

Comment: @RobertoAllende, yes you're right, but why put the business logic into the db logic? perhaps one day the team doesn't need a coach, or you need multiple coaches? That's what I explained above, make your models more generic and DRY, it will be future proof even if requirements change. Instead of database, put the logic in application layer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't agree so easy with **@Anzel**, and since the name of the question is

> What are the benefits of having two models instead of one?

I'll try to give my two cents. But before i start i want to place some quotes from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).

> It doesn’t matter which model has the ManyToManyField, but you should
>   only put it in one of the models – not both.
>
> Generally, ManyToManyField instances should go in the object that’s
>   going to be edited on a form. In the above example, toppings is in
>   Pizza (rather than Topping having a pizzas ManyToManyField ) because
>   it’s more natural to think about a pizza having toppings than a
>   topping being on multiple pizzas. The way it’s set up above, the Pizza
>   form would let users select the toppings.

Basically that's the first thing you should have in mind when creating a `M2M` relation *(your `TeamCoach` model is that, but more on that in a second)* which one is the object holding the relation. What would be more suitable for your problem - choosing a coach for a team when you create it, or choosing a team for a person when you create it? IF you ask me i would prefer the second variant and keep the `teams` inside of the `Person` class.

Now lets go to the next section of the docs

#### Extra fields on many-to-many relationships

> When you’re only dealing with simple many-to-many relationships such
>   as mixing and matching pizzas and toppings, a standard ManyToManyField
>   is all you need. However, sometimes you may need to associate data
>   with the relationship between two models.
>
> For example, consider the case of an application tracking the musical
>   groups which musicians belong to. There is a many-to-many relationship
>   between a person and the groups of which they are a member, so you
>   could use a ManyToManyField to represent this relationship. However,
>   there is a lot of detail about the membership that you might want to
>   collect, such as the date at which the person joined the group.
>
> For these situations, Django allows you to specify the model that will
>   be used to govern the many-to-many relationship. You can then put
>   extra fields on the intermediate model. The intermediate model is
>   associated with the ManyToManyField using the through argument to
>   point to the model that will act as an intermediary.

That's actually the answer of your question, having an intermediate model give you the ability to store additional data about the collection. Consider the situation where a coach moves to another team next season, if you just update the `M2M` relation, you will loose the track of his past teams where he was coaching. Or you will never be able to answer the question who was the coach of that team at year XXX. So if you need more data, go with intermediate model. This is also were @Anzel going wrong, the `type` field is an additional data of that intermediate model, it's place must be inside it.

Now here is how i would probably create the relations:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', through='TeamRole')


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class TeamRole(models.Model):
    COACH = 1
    PLAYER = 2
    CHEERLEADER = 3
    ROLES = (
        (COACH, 'Coach'),
        (PLAYER, 'Player'),
        (CHEERLEADER, 'Cheerleader'),
    )
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLES)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    date_left = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

How will I query this? Well, I can use the `role` to get what type of `persons` I'm looking for, and I can also use the `date_left` field to get the current `persons` participating in that team right now. Here are a few example methods:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    #...

    def get_current_team(self):
        return self.teams.filter(teamrole__date_left__isnull=True).get()


class Team(models.Model):
    #...

    def _get_persons_by_role(self, role, only_active):
        persons = self.person_set.filter(teamrole__role=role)
        if only_active:
            return persons.filter(teamrole__date_left__isnull=True)
        return persons

    def get_coaches(self, only_active=True):
        return self._get_persons_by_role(TeamRole.COACH, only_active)

    def get_players(self, only_active=True):
        return self._get_persons_by_role(TeamRole.PLAYER, only_active)
```

Comment: my answer is basically trying to give OP an insight how to manage the model schema. The point is, make them more generic unless fields are necessary. In your approach, I do agree with TeamRole (**BUT** it should be rather an extension to Person type as **Role** than in Team). Person is still tightly coupled with Team, which by design is a Flaw. You cannot reuse Person in other areas, also to simply query Team members, you have to go through unnecessary database hit.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why the `Person` is tightly coupled? The `Person` models is perfectly clean, he has only one field in his table -> the `name` field. Further more here is one  limitation which I notice with your design: A `Person` can have many teams, but he can't have different role for each team. How would you make `Person A` to be `coach` in `Team A` and a `Cheerleader` in `Team B`? That's why the `type` field shouldn't be inside `Person`. And last but not least there are no additional database hits. Getting all the `coaches` for a `Team` for would require equal number of db hits.

Comment: first of all, I'm not predicting what OP is trying to design the app -- I am only giving advice based on real life experience. You're right about Type but then it can be changed to a ManyToMany field you know. To be simple, Person should be individual and not tightly tied to other models unless absolute necessary. My point being is, you can extend your Team model to whatever the App requires, Person on the other hand, should not. Just think of Person being an extended Profile of User... Pizza with Topping is not a good example as it usually has Topping, but Person not with Team.

Comment: And I'm only trying to show the limitations of not using intermediate model :) if I understand you correctly, you think that `Person` is tightly tied to `Team` because of the `teams` field is inside it? We can remove the `teams` field from `Person` and add `persons` inside `Team`, and this wont change anything! Because we use intermediate model there  will be no need to make any migrations on a db level. With proper usage of `related_names` there will be no need to made changes on the code also. That's why i think person is not tightly tied just by having `teams` inside.

Comment: following your logic, you end up building tightly coupled class methods etc. within that model to resolve query related issues. How can you easily migrate / change in between Person & Team? Simply put, this is not flexible at all, not to mention without a clear settings for DB & Application logics is purely a bad design. To be fair, we all try to help OP to understand more about how Models should be handled, I do not want to go on arguing about real world use cases, so we should call it a truce :-)

Comment: ОК, let's have a truce ;) BTW you have probably notice that I'm not a native speaker *(and also a writer :D)* so if somehow my comments seemed unfriendly I apologize it was not intentional. Regards.

Comment: hey no worries we all come up to share ideas & experiences and to learn, that's how it makes for a great SO community :-)